# With Quasar, images are displayed in the browser but not in the emulator (or actual phone)

Tags: image, quasar-framework, quasar

I've written some Vue 3 code which works well in the browser but not in the emulator (for Android or iPhone) or on the actual phones.

The code loops through (v-for) a list of jpegs (1 to 3 currently) and displays the image, like this:

```
<template>       
   <div v-for="contact in contactDetails.contacts"
            :key="contact.id">
            <div><img :src="getImage(contact.id)" class="flex-container" alt=""       style="height: 300px"></div>
   </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  const getImage = (imageData) =>{
  return `src/assets/${imageData}.jpeg`
</script>
```

As I said, the above (slightly truncated code) works on the browser but not on the emulators or the actual phones.

I have looked around on the web but can't find the solution. Guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I should add that I am using Capacitor

Answer (score 0):

So ... I fixed it.

The most important thing is that in Quasar your images have to be in, or in a folder under, the public folder.

Getting the path correct was a little bit difficult for me but the console would give clues on where it was looking (where it would give an error message along the lines of GET https://local/host/.../image.jpg or whatever).

I didn't have to do the fancy schmancy inserting a function into the :src URL as above. So my code looks something like this:

```
<div v-for="contact in contactDetails.contacts"
        :key="contact.id">
    <div class="linkTitle">{{ contact.service }}</div>
    <img class="flex-containter" :src="`/${contact.imageURL}`" style="height:200px"/>
   </div>
```

Comment: And this worked on Android and iOS (emulators and also apk and on the iOS in dev mode).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with my Quasar + Capacitor setup. Images in the /public folder worked just fine when running the dev server, but whenever I actually ran `quasar build -m capacitor -T android|ios` the resulting package had the asset URLs mixed up.

It was anticipating that everything in my public folder would be under the "localhost/assets/" directory, but they had actually been copied over just at "localhost/". Trying to tweak it by changing the Vite base URL options didn't do anything, so I ended up just moving everything in my /public folder into /public/assets and that solved it!

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same thing.
i had to generate bundles in order test them directly on the phone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).